# How to loop through array after data fetching is completed?

Tags: reactjs

I am a little new to react, and I am trying to loop through a list of menu items  after it has been loaded. I set the sate to empty and put a condition to only start to use the .map() when the state is not empty. But i keep getting TypeError: menu_items.map is not a function.
I know that it gets loaded because when i do a console.log(menu_items) it shows the menu item.
I am little but confused on this one. Any help would be really appreciated.

```
import {useEffect} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import {getMenu} from '../service/thunks'


const StoreMenu = ({loadMenu,match,menu_items}) => {

    useEffect(()=> loadMenu(match.params.id),[]);


if(menu_items !== "") {
    {
        menu_items.map(menu_item => console.log(menu_item.item_name))
    }
}
    return (<div> tesr</div>);


}

const  mapStateToProps = state => (

    {
        menu_items : state.menuItems

    }

)


const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => (

    {

        loadMenu: (store_id) => dispatch(getMenu(store_id))

    }

)


export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(StoreMenu);
```

Comment: `menu_items` must not be an Array, so there is no `.map()` prototype function. Can you check with [Array.isArray(menu_items)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray)?

Comment: Thanks. That was the issue. It wasnt an array.

Answer (score 1):

Fix the code to:

```
if (menu_items && menu_items.length > 0) {
    menu_items.map(menu_item => console.log(menu_item.item_name))
}
return ( 
   // Create JSX here.
);
```